# generating more than one image with a for loop

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to the php gd library. I have developed code for generating an image with the gd library and the creation of the image is successful. I have tried to generate more images of same type with a for loop but when i tried to add a button near all the images it didn't fit on one image. It appears like this:

[image: image of misfitted buttons]

My code

```
<?php
$num = 5;
for ($j = 1; $j <= $num; $j++) {
echo "<img src=yeah.php /><br><br>";
echo "<button>clickme</button>";
}
?>
```

I want to fit the button in all the 5 images ..Hope you guys can help me out

Thanks in advance..

Comment: define `fit the button in all the 5 images`

Comment: @vico have you got any idea on how to acheive this ?

Comment: I can't achieve what you did not explain in details, what exactly does fit button in all the 5 images mean?

Comment: do you want to show: image button _new row_ image button ... ?

Comment: @vico ad you can see the first image is alone ..it has not click me button.and see that last line and see a click me button which is standing alone ..i need 5 images with that click me button

Comment: @Andron i need to display click me button on the first line with  the picture .and a picture with click me button on the last line..

Comment: Your error comes from a misunderstanding of HTML. Why did you put the <br>s if you wanted the image beside the button? Sorry. Had to downvote. It's not a GD problem but an HTML problem.

Comment: Just put the `<br>` tags after the `<button>` ones

Comment: @OlivierH thanks ..:) ..oops i didnt noticed it ..thanks ..:D

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$num = 5;
for ($j = 1; $j <= $num; $j++) {
echo "<img src=yeah.php /><button>clickme</button><br><br>";
}
?>
```

not sure if it is answer worthy..
this is just a basic html output you output a `image` then 2 `linebreaks` then your `button`
and repeated this process 5 times given the loop that is why you have the current final results.